# DateField getting value

Tags: gxt

I have problem with getting value of `com.gwtext.client.widgets.form.DateField` component. I would like to parse date on the server side so I'm using method `getText()` instead of `getValue()`. Problem is that `DateField` component has format YYYY-MM-DD but if I print date value I get result "Thu Sep 17 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0200", so the format is different. I thought that only `getValueAsString()` result will be like that "Thu Sep 17 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0200", but `getText()` should return "2009-09-17" :(, but it doesn't. How can I get the value in the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatters, they are part of GWT framework

```
 DateField date = new DateField();
 String result = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date.getValue());
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

use `getRawValue()`